# .then of Promise.all result never executes

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am trying to use `Promise.all` and `map` instead of the forEach loop so the task can be asynchronous. All of the promises in the `Promise.all` array get executed and are resolved. The code looks like this:

```
loadDistances() {
    //return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let rrr;
      let arr = [];
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {            
          // resp.coords.latitude
          rrr = resp;
          console.log(rrr + "              rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.distancelist = this.af.list('/profiles/stylists');

            let x = 0;
            this.subscription6 = this.distancelist.subscribe(items => {

              let mapped = items.map((item) => {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                  let rr;
                  //console.log(JSON.stringify(item) + "               *((*&*&*&*&^&*&*&*(&*(&*&*(&(&(&*(              :::" + x);
                  if(item.address == "") {
                    /*if(!item.picURL) {
                      item.picURL = 'assets/blankprof.png';
                    }*/
                    //arr.push({'pic':item.picURL, 'salon':item.username, 'distance':"No Address"});
                    //x++;
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log(item.address + " is the address empty??????");
                    this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(item.address)
                      .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult) => {
                        console.log("I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&*");
                          rr = this.round(this.distance(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude, rrr.coords.latitude, rrr.coords.longitude, "M"), 1);
                          if(!item.picURL) {
                            item.picURL = 'assets/blankprof.png';
                          }
                          arr.push({'pic':item.picURL, 'salon':item.username, 'distance':rr});
                          console.log("push to the array of results");
                          //x++;
                          /*console.log(items.length + "         length   /    x:        " + x);
                          if(items.length - x == 1) {
                            console.log("getting resolved in geocoder ^&^&^&&^^&^&^&");
                            resolve(arr);
                          }*/
                          resolve();
                        }).catch(e => {
                          console.log(e.message + " caught this error");
                          /*x++;
                          if(items.length - x == 1) {
                            resolve(arr);
                          }*/
                          resolve();
                        })
                  }

                })
              });

              let results = Promise.all(mapped);
              results.then(() => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) + " :FOSIEJO:SFJ::EFIJSEFIJS:EFJS:IO THIS IODIOSJ:FDSIJ :DIS");
                arr.sort(function(a,b) {
                  return a.distance - b.distance;
                });

                this.distances = arr.slice();
              })

            });//);
          }, 1500)




      /*}).catch((error) => {
        this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        console.log('Error getting location', error.message);
        resolve();
      });*/

    });


  }
```

The console output is:

```
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:27]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:27]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:28]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:28]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:29]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:29]  console.log: push to the array of results 
[12:38:29]  console.log: I AM IN THE GEOCODING ***&&*&*&*&* 
[12:38:29]  console.log: push to the array of results
```

The alternating messages make it seem like it worked and all of the promises got resolved. But when I do `Promise.all` this line never happens in the console:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) + " :FOSIEJO:SFJ::EFIJSEFIJS:EFJS:IO THIS IODIOSJ:FDSIJ :DIS");`

So it is not reaching the `then` of the `Promise.all` `results`.

Comment: Oh my, what a mess this code is. It does so many different things. But to even start cleaning this up, what is the timeout of 1500ms for? And what is `this` in general? since `this` seems to hold pretty much everything from state over sub-modules to utility-functions like `round()`.

Comment: and when you are up to it, switch your code to async/await and it will be alot cleaner to read -> https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/09/typescript-2-1-async-await-for-es3-es5

Comment: @Thomas thanks for pointing some things out...as I am a little new to ionic/angular/typescript. The 1500ms delay is there because if it isn't, the code inside `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {` runs before the position coordinates are actually obtained. I am using `this` to refer to the classes methods and properties, as well as injected modules (`constructor(xxx: XXXXXX)`). I have been learning some of these things and going very quickly at the same time because I was not given much time to do this...I would have liked to pay more attention to best practices.

Comment: @Lostfields thanks for the suggestion...I have used that in places but wasn't sure if there was a main difference besides readability

Comment: @Thomas I just took out the settimeout...it wasn't needed afterall, whatever was happening that was wrong may have been fixed after figuring out Promise.all

Comment: and one more thing, I always think that a method should only write to internal variables. I would have placed variable "arr" inside mapped and return the arr from that promise. Then you could handle the results with the arr values. One problem it is array of arrays, but you may flatten it with "[].concat.apply([], await Promise.all(mapped))"

Comment: Yah I would normally do it that way...I have had no time and this is my first ionic app so things have gotten messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have code paths that don't resolve, specifically:

```
if(item.address == "") {
  /*if(!item.picURL) {
    item.picURL = 'assets/blankprof.png';
  }*/
  //arr.push({'pic':item.picURL, 'salon':item.username, 'distance':"No Address"});
  //x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy getting into deadlocks like @andy-gaskell pointed out when creating new Promises. To avoid that you better do one of these; All of these may throw an impossible error or return 1.

```
function promiseWithTryCatch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let result;
      // your code

      resolve(result);
    }
    catch(ex) {
      reject(ex);
    }
  })
}

function promiseWithResolve() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      let result;
      // your code

      return result; 
    })
}

async function promiseWithAsync() {
  let result;
  // your code

  return result;
}
```

Replace the comment with your code and place the ending result into the variable result. If your code contains async code, you better make a new function with the same pattern and return that as the result, eg: result = [promise method]

- The most scary one is "new Promise", if any code does not resolve or reject it will end in a "dead-lock", that's why it is important to have a try/catch.
- If you are using Promise.resolve() it will catch any errors inside .then but don't do any code outside .then, otherwise you have to catch exception and return a Promise.reject(new Error())
- The safest is async function, since any "throw" will return a Promise.reject, and "return" will return a Promise.resolve

Play around with this example, but I had to comment out async/await since this snippet tool doesn't handle ES2016.

```js
function nestedPromise(num) {
  return Promise.resolve(' myNestedValue is ' + num);
}

function promiseWithTryCatch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let mynumber = 2 + 5;

      nestedPromise(mynumber)
        .then((answer) => {
          resolve(answer.trim());
        })
        .catch(ex => {
          // error handling for async-code
          reject(ex);
        })
    }
    catch(ex) {
      // error handling for sync-code
      reject(ex);
    }
  })
}

function promiseWithResolve() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      let mynumber = 2 + 5;

      return nestedPromise(mynumber);
    })
    .then((answer) => {
      // do something with the answer
      return answer.trim();
    })
}

/*
async function promiseWithAsync() {
  let mynumber = 2 + 5;
  let answer = await nestedPromise(mynumber);
  
  return answer.trim();
}
*/

promiseWithTryCatch()
  .then(answer => console.log('promiseWithTryCatch result is ' + answer))
   .catch(err => console.log('promiseWithAsync error is ' + err.message));
   
promiseWithResolve()
  .then(answer => console.log('promiseWithResolve result is ' + answer))
  .catch(err => console.log('promiseWithResolve error is ' + err.message));

/*
promiseWithAsync()
  .then(answer => console.log('promiseWithAsync result is' + answer))
  .catch(err => console.log('promiseWithAsync error is ' + err.message));
*/
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, could you explain a little more how I would use these methods to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: added an example and more description for each case