# How to handle the order when executing the callbacks?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, callback, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase for authentication in my angular2 app and I'm having a issue with callbacks. Here is my code segment to identify whether a user has logged in or not.

```
verifyLogin(url: string): boolean {
var myUser = null;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    myUser = user;
    console.log("sdfsdfsd");
    console.log(myUser);
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
console.log("check");
console.log(myUser);
if(myUser){
  return true;
}
console.log(myUser);
this.router.navigate(['/admin/signin']);
return false;
```

}

This verifyLogin function will return true if user has logged in and false otherwise. But the problem is bottom part which contains the if condition executes before executing the callback. I can't return inside the callback as well. How to fix this?

Comment: Remember, callback is async. If you are going to use the result of a callback then your method "verifyLogin" is asynchronous. Use @samAlvin answer, making it return a Promise.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to make `verifyLogin()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This way, `verifyLogin()` will only return either `true` or `false` after `onAuthStateChanged()` finished.

```
verifyLogin(url: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var myUser = null;
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                myUser = user;
                console.log("sdfsdfsd");
                console.log(myUser);
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And then you can call the `verifyLogin()` like this:

```
verifyLogin("someUrl").then(isLoggedIn => {
    if (isLoggedIn == false) {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/signin']);
    }
});
```

Comment: also, when creating a new Promise, you better have a try/catch wrapping to make sure you don't end up in a deadlock. If auth() throws an error, this will never resolve ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025734/then-of-promise-all-result-never-executes/46067409#46067409 )